# How to use wildcard in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to rename a file but I'm having a hard time changing it.

Basically I have a file named scorpion.jpg. What I want is change scorpion.jpg to default.jpg

scorpion.jpg is a uploaded file so it can be any name. This is what I have so far.

```
   rename('path_to_image/' . '*.jpg', 'path_to_image/' . 'default.jpg');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `exec('mv "'.$path.'*.jpg" "'.$path.'".default.jpg');`

[exec function manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Hope it helped !

**EDIT 1 :**

So, to stay full PHP i would do this

```
$scan = glob($path.'*.jpg');

if(!empty($scan)){
    if( !rename($path.$scan[0], $path.$newName)){
        echo 'Failed rename';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Renamed!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to rename a file without having to issue system commands with the exec function? Trying to stay pure php. Thanks

Comment: Well, then, depends, if you just uploaded that file, you can get its name from the input field. If its a file on the server, and you just don't know his name, you can just try to list all files finishing with .jpg and rename the first one in default.jpg, editing my answer

Comment: Well the problem is that there's only going to be one file in this folder and that's the profile_image. When someone uploads it to the server, I wanted it renamed to default.(image_ext). The thing is when I search for the image uploaded it can be anything etc image.jpg or hello.jpg. I'm trying to find it by using a wildcard like *.jpg but it's saying that the file or directory doesn't exist. But I"m looking at the path and the file is there. Confused at the moment.

Comment: On upload, check the `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];` ;)